# Get data from all tables ending with a specific string

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, information-schema

I'm looking for a query that gets the nextval column from a lot of different tables ending with "_seq".

I know how to get the names of the tables...

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%seq'
```

But i couldn't find how to get the values from all those tables at once...

All those tables have the same column.

Comment: take a look at information_schema.columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only achieve this with dynamic SQL. As you're using SQL Sevrer 2012, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method to create the "delimited" `UNION ALL` query. I've also added the name of the schema and table into the query's dataset, as I assume this would be valuable information:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name],'''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF + 
                         N'       N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF + 
                         N'       NextVal' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name])
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE t.[name] LIKE '%[_]seq'
                    AND c.[name] = N'NextVal'
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,11,N'') + N';'

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

As there's no data to test with, you'll need to use your "best friend" to debug if it doesn't work.